# TemplateDoesNotExist at /post/new/ When i host the django project on heroku

Tags: python, django, templates

I created an app with django on my local machine and it works perfectly with all the templates and html files going to the correct locations but when i tried to host it on heroku, it loads the home page but when i try to create a new blog it says templates does not exist.

This is the error I keep getting:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://ifecrudapp.herokuapp.com/post/new/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
blog/post_form.html
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 47, in select_template
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.4
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python39.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages']


Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /app/templates/blog/post_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /app/blog/templates/blog/blog/post_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/blog/templates/blog/post_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/users/templates/blog/post_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/crispy_forms/templates/blog/post_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/blog/post_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/blog/post_form.html (Source does not exist)
```

Comment: Please share the relevant view, and the filetree.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once , i once wrote

```
{% extends 'base.html ' %}
```

instead of

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

yeah the single white space after the base.html was a bug in heroku but not in localhost

-i would suggest to carefully inspect if you have any extra white spaces in any of the code where you defined the template name, also inspect the template file names in directory folder for any extra whitespaces
.